# Using $(this) from within jQuery.extend()

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, object, jquery-plugins

I'm using the [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/), and want that this plugin is used on every `form.ajaxify`. So I have this:

```
$('form.ajaxify').ajaxForm(
    // the options
);
```

With the HTML `<form class="ajaxify" ...> ... </form>`.

Now, I have some options that I want to pass always, like `dataType:'json'`. In addition to that, I want to be able to put more options in the `form` tag, like this:

```
<form class="ajaxify" ... data-ajaxify-options='{"target":"#x"}'> ... </form>
```

This is valid according to [the docs on `.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

So I thought I'd use [`jQuery.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/). I tried to put it like this:

```
$('.ajaxify').ajaxForm(
    jQuery.extend(
        {
            dataType: 'json'
        }, 
        $(this).data('ajaxify-options')
    )
);
```

However, this doesn't work: only the literal object is passed, and nothing is extended. I *suppose* this doesn't work because `$(this)` doesn't refer anymore to the `form.ajaxify` element. Is this correct? Normally one could store the `$(this)` in a variable, however, that would mean complicating the code, right? It wouldn't be possible on one line anymore. Or is there another solution?

Comment: The way you're calling `$.extend()`, the object being extended is that object literal you're passing in as the first parameter. You're not saving a reference to that object anywhere, so even though the call to `$.extend()` "works", you can't access the results. *edit* never mind I'm dense or crazy :)

Comment: @Pointy I'm not sure if I get what you mean, but I don't need to access the results; they're used as the options for `$(.ajaxify).ajaxForm`.

Comment: @Pointy: I think `$.extend` returns the extended object.

Comment: What exactly doesn't "work"? I don't see how this has something to do with `$(this)`.

Comment: @FelixKling good point. I'll add it to the question as well, but what doesn't work is this: the result of `$.extend` is just the first object (the literal); nothing from the `.data()` call is extended.

Comment: Sorry I saw a `function()` header where there was none :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I suppose this doesn't work because `$(this)` doesn't refer anymore to the `form.ajaxify` element. Is this correct?

Yes, although `this` never did refer to that element. It does only inside of callback functions called by jQuery, however you are using it for building the *argument* to the `ajaxForm` call. `this` will refer to whatever [the `this` context currently refers to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

> Normally one could store the `$(this)` in a variable, however, that would mean complicating the code, right?

You would store `$('form.ajaxify')` in a variable, as `$(this)` is meaningless, but yes that's how it needs to be done. It doesn't really "complicate" the code, though:

```
var form = $('.ajaxify');
form.ajaxForm($.extend({
    dataType: 'json'
}, form.data('ajaxify-options')));
```

If you wanted to avoid the variable, you'd need to repeat the selector, which is a bad practise.

For a snippet that works for multiple forms in a selected collection, you can use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to apply the method on every single element with possibly different options - and in its callback, you can now use `this`:

```
$('.ajaxify').each(function() {
    // caching $this=$(this) is possible as well, but not as necessary
    $(this).ajaxForm($.extend({
        dataType: 'json'
    }, $(this).data('ajaxify-options')));
});
```

Comment: Will this work with several forms on one page? How does the `.data()` function know which `.ajaxify` is currently being 'ajaxFormed'?

Comment: It doesn't, no; I had assumed you only had a single form on your page.

Comment: This works, thank you very much. A pity that it's not possible with a oneliner though.